# MySQL Safe Mode: What Satisfies the Requirements?

Tags: mysql, safe-mode

I know that I can turn off Safe Mode in MySQL, so I’m not trying to work that one out.

I have a simple table:

```
create table rubbish(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    stuff text,
    nonsense text
);
```

Here `id` is the primary key.

With Safe Mode turned on, I try the following:

```
update rubbish set nonsense=stuff where id=id;          -- fails
update rubbish set nonsense=stuff where id is not null; -- fails
update rubbish set nonsense=stuff where id<>0;          -- works
```

The error message, like most error messages in MySQL is unhelpful:

```
You are using safe update mode and you tried to update
a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column
```

In all cases, I used the key column, so the message explains nothing. What does MySQL actually require me to do with the key column?

Comment: Where have you tried this, in Workbench?

Comment: No, in a different Application on the Mac (SQL Pro). That shouldn’t make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL `SQL_SAFE_UPDATES` **prevents you from misusing keys** in `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements. MySQL engine is optimized to understand some conditions given.

---

```
... WHERE `id` IS NOT NULL;
```

A primary key can never be null so this is always `true`. Same goes with

```
... WHERE `id`=`id`;
```

and

```
... WHERE TRUE;
```

---

These are considered as misuses of keys. Hense they are prohibited.

Comment: Great answer. Basically, it's trying to prevent you from blowing away the whole table accidentally.

Comment: Note that the `WHERE TRUE` example wouldn’t satisfy the requirement anyway, as it doesn’t include the Key column.

Comment: @Manngo I have just left it there to show that the above conditions are identical to that. So a future reader may understand it well.